# .NET Core 3.0 Default routing to an Area

Tags: c#, routes, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm currently working on a .Net Core 3.0 project and I'm having trouble with the default routing using the UseEndpoints in the Configure function in start up.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    areaName: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I want the default routing to be the same as the MapAreaRoute but I'm having trouble doing so. Currently the routing is working as it's supposed to since I've added a RedirectToAction method in the HomeController outside of the Area

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "default" });
    }
}
```

Is there any other way of doing this? I've tried adding the same pattern for both routes and messed around with it a little bit but none of it seems to work. For reference I have a .Net core 2.1 project with a similar setup and I had no issues with it

```
//NOTE, this is from the .Net Core 2.1 project and is using UseMvc and not UseEndpoints
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapAreaRoute(
        name: "default",
        areaName: "Users",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

TLDR: Having trouble with default routing to an Area controller without the use of a RedirectToAction method in a controller outside of the Area